# Relating a scoring mechanism to entropy and homogeneity

Tags: probability, clustering, accuracy, entropy

#### Context

I'm working on some clustering algorithms, and my boss wants me to grade them. My go-to method has been to measure homogeneity, completeness, and v-measure.

However, since we are presenting findings to clients, he is interested in showing accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity. I informed him these are binary classification metrics and require knowledge TP/FP etc. To have these, we need some sort of mapping from classes to clusters, where those two sets may have different cardinalities. So he came up with some alternative formulations of TP/FP/TN/FN.

Here is his algorithm. It assumes the best case where there are 7 clusters and 7 classes.

```
for (i=1, i<=7, i++ )
    for j=i + 1, j++
        if (class(xi) == class(xj)) and
            if (cluster(xi) == cluster(xj)):
                TP++
            else:
                FN++
        else:
            if (cluster(xi) == cluster(xj)):
                FP++
            else:
                TN++
```

I am very suspicious that these definitions just lead back to an analog homogeneity and completeness. I've been trying to determine if my suspicion is true.

#### Question

Either by proof or by intuition, are these two formulations similar or not?

#### What I tried.

For fun, I attempted a formal proof that his idea equates (roughly) to homogeneity. I was never good at probability and it's been a few years since I was in a classroom writing proofs. Here's what I tried:

---

So first I looked up homogeneity and found that the formula is

$$
H(C|K) = - \sum_{x \in C, y \in K}p(x, y)\text{ln}\frac{p(x, y)}{p(x)} 
$$

Then I thought about how to formulate his definition of a true positive. This is what I came up with:

$$
\begin{align}
P(TP) &= P(C=x)(1 - P(K \not = x)) \\
&= P(C=x)P(K=x) \\
&= P(C=x, K=x) 
\end{align}
$$

Next, note the algorithm sums true positives, so:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_x P(TP) &= \sum_x P(C=x)(1 - P(K \not = x)) \\
&= \sum_x P(C=x, K=x) 
\end{align}
$$

So things are starting to look similar. Assuming that the above is true, I see that there are similar terms of $P(x, y)$ and $P(C=x, K=x)$. But I don't know if they are actually the same.

At any rate, I'd like to know if my suspicion is correct. I don't need a proof, but it would be awesome because I'll have something to study and learn from to keep my math/stats at least a little fresh.

Comment: Why not comment your code. What, for example, is class(xi) ?

Comment: Since we are talking about clusters and classification metrics, class means class of point xi, and cluster means cluster of point xi.